# CakePHP routing not redirecting correctly

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

I have a problem and i have no idea what's wrong.

I have build  a basic authentication system, simple one. but what i noticed is that the URL- from the side bar is different from the one that is generatet from cakephp for example:

```
http://localhost/sitename/users
```

is the url that displays on toolbar.

When i  do:

```
echo Router::url($this->here, true );
```

the result is:

```
http://localhost/sitename/sitename/users
```

The site still works, but time after time generates an error such as:

```
http://localhost/sitename/sitename/users/ 

Missing Controller

Error:  SitenameController could not be found.

Error:  Create the class SitenameController below in file: app\Controller\SitenameController.php
<?php class SitenameController extends AppController {

}
```

So i dont know what is causing the problem...
If someone, anyone could help me i would  very appruciate it...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is in a subdirectory so you should use

```
Router::url(null, true);
```

If the `$url` param is `null` *the method will find the address to the actual controller/action*. Read more [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#Router::url).

From the book:

*`$this->request->here` contains the full address to the current request.*

The full address includes the subdirectory as well. So if you use `Router::url()` with the `$full` param set to `true` it "duplicates" the subdirectory.

Comment: Thanx for your replay @rocknrollcanneverdie.  but what worries mi is that why is generated that way, i mean when the error happens, or to be more specific how to prevent that kind of error.

Comment: The reason of missing controller error is the wrong URL. You can avoid the wrong URL generated by CakePHP if you follow the answer above.

Comment: `Router::connect("/", array("controller" => "users", "action" => "index","home"));
//Router::connect("/", array("controller" => "pages", "action" => "display", "home"));
Router::connect("/pages/*", array("controller" => "pages", "action" => "display"));
CakePlugin::routes();
require CAKE . "Config" . DS . "routes.php";`

This are my routes, and i dont know where the problem is :/..??

@rocknrollcanneverdie